# Solar excess power dump

Tags: solar-cell, heater

I have a 24 V 5000 W 120 A Victron multiplus inverter charger to a Autotransformer 120/240 100A to make split phase on my daughter's off-grid house.

600 Ah lithium batteries (4x 12V @300 Ah), 5000 W solar. (No grid) possibly a generator in the future.

The Victron has two AC outputs. AC1 is primary and AC2 would normally be high loads to shed if there was a grid failure.

AC2 out, I've programmed two assistants for state of charge SOC relay to come on @ 99% and go off @ 96%. This should activate the AC2 when the batteries are full.

AC2 puts out one leg 240 V single phase.

I want to divert my excess solar output to a water heater, 40 gallons 2 element.

So here’s the question:

What elements for “single phase” 240 V? I guess I'm concerned with the amp draw off of batteries and how to work that out.

1500 W x2 @ 240 V elements I believe will be 12.5 amps.

But... 1500 W x2 @24 V = 125 amps

Isn't this a huge draw?

Am I thinking about this correctly? I hope this isn’t too convoluted.

Comment: Single-phase 240V vs split-phase 240V makes absolutely no difference to a water heater element - current drawn will be identical. Your math is correct (but optimistic since it doesn't account for inverter losses/inefficiency), so you'll probably see closer to 140A draw from the 24V batteries bank. Yes that is a huge draw ... and tells you that using batteries to heat water is usually not the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty common to dump excess PV power into a water heater, but as you noticed, the power rating of ready-made off the shelf heating elements is not a good match for this.

Using a fixed high power load, like 3kW in your case, also means that if you have less excess power than this, the battery will go through short charge and discharge cycles.

Ideally you'd want a variable power heater to dump your excess PV power. Here people who run grid tied inverters use triac dimmers on the water heater, controlled by measuring how much power is exported to the grid.

In your case, you could control it by monitoring battery charge current on the Victron via modbus, using an algorithm like: if battery SOC is >95%, attempt to keep battery current near zero by modulating the heater. The drawback is EMI and noise generated by the high power dimmer, plus a piss poor power factor.

Another low tech solution is to get a water heater with a three phase heating element. So it comes with three resistors instead of one. Then using a bunch of relays you can turn on one, two, three resistors, or wire two in series for lower power.

Your two phase element could be used in a similar manner: if you run both resistors in series on 120V instead of 240V you get 1/4 the power, so 750W. If you run one resistor on 120V you get 1500W. And if you run both resistors as designed you get 3000W. So you can do three power levels with just a few relays/triacs.

This will not be supported by the Victron's switched output, but... if you want maximum simplicity you could use this output to drive a relay that switches the resistors wired as 750W or 1500W using one of the 120V phases of the transformer. If you want to do a bit of programming, you can check battery current via modbus and play with the three power levels.

Some people will suggest running the heating element on DC from the solar panels: the thermostat switch is not rated for DC, which means it would arc and explode. So the heater would have to be operated without the mechanical thermostat as a safety. Not recommended.

There's another way to dump excess power: inverter heat pumps, which are able to operate at a wide range of power, from 25% to full power. If you get one which can be controlled, for example via modbus, and you don't mind a bit of programming you can control it to absorb excess solar power. So you get free air conditioning, and the more sun, the hotter it gets, the more free AC.